# Create dataframe from list of dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to create a dataframe where the columns are all the individual values from each key. For example, if the dictionary looks like this:

```
d = {'gender': 'female',
     'company': ['nike', 'adidas'],
     'location': ['chicago', 'miami'],
     'plan': 'high'}
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
female  nike  adidas  chicago  miami  high
1       1     1       1        1      1
```

Comment: I think you need to explain this question a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `explode` + `value_counts`

```
df=pd.Series(d).explode().value_counts().to_frame(0).T
   chicago  female  nike  miami  high  adidas
0        1       1     1      1     1       1
```

Comment: I get the error "Series object has no attribute 'explode'". Can I not use explode when there is a list (like for 'company' and 'location')?

Comment: @hirshg update your panda to most current one , explode is after 0.25

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive solution but it works. The idea is that:

1. organize that `d` dictionary into a counter dictionary such as

```
{'female': 1,
 'nike': 1,
 'adidas': 1,
 'chicago': 1,
 'miami': 1,
 'high': 1}
```

2. and then from there, you can create a pandas df

Here's the code:

```
# 1. create list to count 
out = []
for value in d.values():
    if isinstance(value, list):
        out.extend(value)
    else:
        out.append(value)
# out = ['female', 'nike', 'adidas', 'chicago', 'miami', 'high']

# 2. count occurrence of each unique item in this out list
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(out)

# 3. pandas df from dictionary
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([Counter(out)])

# output:
# female  nike  adidas  chicago  miami  high
# 1       1     1       1        1      1
```

Comment: The data comes like that from another source, so I can't just organize the dictionary like that, unfortunately.